# Query to return a row that has all values in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temporary table that gets populated through some business logic, and shows Products which are requested by a customer and the Sellers who have that product available in their inventory.

Here is a simplistic look at table's content:

```
ID  ProductID   SellerID
1   1000           1
2   2000           1
3   3000           1
4   1000           2
5   3000           2
6   1000           3
7   3000           3
```

I need to write a **T-SQL** query that ONLY returns the SellerID (or list of SellerID) who have ALL of the requested products in their inventory. In this specific example, we can see that only SellerID = 1 has ALL products (ProductID's  1000, 2000, and 3000), so the query should return only ONE result set:

```
SellerID = 1
```

There are scenarios where multiple sellers might have all products, so the proper list of sellerID's should be returned. (Please feel free to edit the question's title as you see fit).

Any thoughts or solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select sellerid,
from t
group by sellerid
having count(*) = (select count(distinct productid) from t);
```

This assumes that the rows are not duplicated.

I would add that you may have sellers that do not have all the products.  If you want the sellers with the *most* products:

```
select s.*
from (select sellerid, count(*) as num_products,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by sellerid
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also phrase this without the subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties sellerid, count(*) as num_products
from t
group by sellerid
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You aggregate by `SellerID` and filter with a `having` clause that compares the count of distinct `ProductID`s of each `SellerID` to the overall number of distinct `ProductID`s available in the table:

```
select SellerID
from mytable t
group by SellerID
having count(distinct ProductID) = (select count(distinct ProductID) from mytable)
```